# I want to know which is most suitable word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Following episode three, which saw innocent 'faithful' Imran go home after being falsely accused as a traitor,
>
> the atmosphere grew tense as John grew frustrated with a fellow faithful, Aaron, over his upset reaction to being accused of being a traitor. Following the exchange, viewers took to Twitter to suggest John should be the traitors’ next 'victim'..

**according to above paragraph both Imran and Aron are good.but viewrs hate John .

My question is: we normally mention "victim" as a good person.. he is a helpless person. but I dont understand why do they use "victim" for Rude guy (in a game)and I want to know which is most suitable word use for this

I read this because my teacher suggested this for vocublary practise.

my be my question looks like silly..  I am a new learner.
can you please help me to understand?

Thankyou

Comment: Episode Three of what? A victim is a person to whom something bad happens. You don't have to be a 'good' or 'helpless' person to be the victim of an accident or attack.

Comment: you are right .. 
but 
Eg someone slaps me..
I am a victim .
He is a crimanal .
Am I correct ?
 here, john did somthing wrong in series.how can we say he is a victim . In the series he would be in next elemantion.

sorry for my poor english

Comment: If 'the traitors' attack John, he will be victim of that attack even if he is considered a 'bad' person. You still haven't told us what series you are talking about!

Answer (score 1):

A 'victim' is someone who has been hurt, damaged, or even killed by someone or something. You might speak of the victims of a serial killer, or the victims of an illness, for example.

In some cases, people may be the victim of random chance, but they can also be deliberately targeted. For example, it may be said that a serial killer deliberately selected their victims.

Sometimes we do use the word in a more lighthearted way. For example, let's say you knew someone that was incredibly boring and they spent ages telling you about something you didn't want to hear but you listened out of politeness. When they finally left you to talk to someone else, you might say "they've found another victim". I admit I don't fully understand your example text or the context, but if you're confused by the term 'victim' because you don't think it is being used in a negative way then I would suggest this is the most likely reason, that you're not used to hearing it in a more lighthearted context. Anyone who has been targeted by someone for something that you, the speaker, think to be unpleasant may describe them as a 'victim' or 'potential victim'.

Comment: the is next line from article. "The traitors better murder John as he’s horrible. Aaron is an angel and must be protected at all costs" ** John is a horrible person, that's why people want to eliminate from shows ..my question why he mentions he would be next victim if Jhon is a horrbile person..he desevres to elemination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when we use the word "victim" we generally mean an innocent person who is unjustly harmed. But the word doesn't imply a perfect person: no one is perfect. If someone was insulting you and screaming obscenities in your face, and then you punched him, the police would call him the "victim" of an assault, even though he is far from totally innocent.

But all that said, note that in the paragraph you quote, "victim" is in quotes. In English, we often put a word in quotes to indicate that we are not using it literally, especially if we are using it in some sarcastic way. Like if a convicted murderer complains that he is being abused in prison because they don't serve his favorite ice cream flavor, someone might say, "Oh, this poor man is a 'victim' of such horrible 'abuse'!" They might put "victim" and "abuse" in quotes to show that they don't really believe that either word applies, and they are mocking his complaints. That appears to be what is being done here. The writer is saying that John should be targetted. As he arguably deserves the punishment here, he is not truly a victim, so they put the word in quotes.

Comment: Completly understand now